# Function to determine a set of numbers are balanced

Tags: statistics, average

Given the following data, based on a 0-100 scale

```
+------------+---------+------------+---------+
|            |  Spd    |    Agi     |  Awr    |
+------------+---------+------------+---------+
|   PlayerA  |   10    |     90     |   50    |
|   PlayerB  |   50    |     50     |   50    |
+------------+---------+------------+---------+
```

Both players AVG is 50, but playerB is much more balanced in his attributes vs playerA, I need a mathematical function to give higher value to player B than player A.

Is there a formula that would possibly penalize the avg calculated value when the numbers are so skewed?

Or, is there a better way to solve this elegantly?

Comment: Do all these numbers have the same range?

Comment: Yes the numbers go from 0-100.

Answer (score 0):

Since the mean for both player A & B are 50. It is obvious that the variance of A is 1066.67 and the variance of B is 0.

The formula I would give is 2000 - VAR so that A's value will be 933.33 while B's value will be 2000.

Comment: More detail would be helpful. The $2000$ does not seem to serve much purpose, just score them as $-var$